# What does "import java.util.Scanner;" mean?

Tags: java

What do the import statements at the beginning of files mean?

As an example, this program calculates the total price which includes sales tax:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class SalesTax { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
              //identifier declarations 
    }
 }
```

Comment: [this could be help](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_scanner.htm)

Comment: [this too](https://www.leepoint.net/language/10basics/import.html)

Comment: this too ...... [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: this means "import the Scanner class which is defined inside util folder inside the java folder".

Comment: tl;dr; - imports are used to know a class you want to use. the `java.util` are representing the path and `Scanner` is the class you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

It tells the compiler, that any time you use a `Scanner`, you mean the one which is located in `java.util`

Comment: Yes. Java.util is a default package and should be present on your compiler